# How to change Operator highlight color in Vim?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, colorscheme, highlight, filetype-c++, color

I just switched to iTerm2 on macOS and found some of its options go to Vim as well. That's the case for fonts, I was able to select a Vim font that I like from iTerm options.

It seems iTerm color options also apply to Vim highligh. But in this case highlight situation is not good enogh for my taste. So I tried to change:

```
:hi Comment ctermfg=gray
```

Changes font color of comments.

I would like to change `=`, `::`, `+`, `-` color, I think these are Operators, so I tried:

```
:hi Operator ctermfg=blue
```

But it seems nothing changes. How should I do that?

If it matters I'm playing with .cpp/.h files.

Answer (score 4):

It indeed looks like `cppOperator` links to `Operator` which links to `Statement` (-> `:hi cppOperator`), but I've never seen these operators displayed differently...

It's just for the keywords. See `syn list cppOperator`. I guess you'd have to add these symbols to the `cppOperator` list. You may need a `syn match` that takes care of not overlapping with `cFloat` and some other syntax groups. Indeed, if we look closely at `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/c.vim` we see that `cFloat` can match `+` or `-` in the possible patterns.

Let's experiment on

```
42 + 12;
42 foobar 12;
```

1. `:syn keyword cOperator +` has no visible effect
2. yet `:syn keyword cOperator foobar` has a visible effect => `syn keyword` is not what we're looking for
3. however `:syn match cOperator "+"` has the effect we are looking for: now we have a match for `+`
4. better yet, we can have `:syn match cOperator "[+/*%^&|<>-]"`, we can observe:

   - there is no interaction with `cFloat`: check `12 * 1e-1` -- my fears were unfounded
   - pointers and addresses will also be highlighted -- excluding these cases will require more tweaking.

     ```
     void * p = &var;
     12 * *p;
     ```

Notes:

- Before the modification, the operators belonged to `cBlock`, now they belong to `cOperator`. We can change the highlighting of `Operator`, it will now also affect these operators.
- Put the new `:syn...` commands into `{rtp}/syntax/c/c-highlight-operator.vim` for instance. -- by `{rtp}`, understand any path in your [`'rtp'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27rtp%27) option.

Comment: Why specifically mention `cFloat`?

Comment: If you look at `cFloat` pattern, you'll see that it can match `+` and `-` signs.

Comment: May I ask how to do that? I mean the syn match.

Comment: I tried `hi cFloat ctermfg=blue` but no changes so far, I was expecting something if it includes `+` and `-`. I guess I'm missing something

Comment: I've edited my answer